# Determining running time

Tags: performance, runtime, nested-loops, pseudocode

could you help me to determine the running time? O, Ω and Θ.

PSEUDOCODE:
`for i := 1 to n do`
    `for j := 1 to n do`
         `if i > j then M[i][j] := 0`
         `else`
             `sum := 0;`
             `d := j-i+1;`
             `l := i;`
             `er := j;`
             `do`
                  `sum := sum + a[l];`
                  `l++;`
             `while (l<=r)`
             `M[i][j] := sum / d;`

I have some problems with nested loops, 2 "for" and an inner "do" for instance.
Could you maybe also suggest a method that could help me to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your do while loop is inside of for like ,

```
for i..n do
for j..n do
do 
while (x<n)
done
done
```

then time complexity will be n*n*n i.e. n^3 with worst case assumptions for "do while" loop.

if your do while loop is outside then it will be,

```
for i..n do
for j..n do
done
done
do 
while (x<n)
```

then (n*n + n) in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Each for loop is valued by the number of repeats. Nesting is multiplying the runtime. Example:

```
for x=0..n
  for y=0..m
```

would be n*m.

Side by side loops would be added, for example:

```
for x=0..n
  for y=0..m
for i=0..p
  for j=0..p
```

would be estimated as n*m+p^2